# Xamarin.Forms.Maps not showing under installed packages

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am following tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

I created a Xamarin.Forms project

I can browse and search for `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` I clicked Install
but I don't see it under installed packages

I see that it has a bunch of dependencies, but they dont seem to install automatically.

Do I need to install all of those one by one?
Is there a way to automatically install all necessary dependencies with correct version like in python?

Thanks,

Comment: unload the csproj and add it on your own: **<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" Version="4.8.0.1364" />**

Comment: No. You could install the Xamarin.Forms.Maps from Github and it would be okay.